# reverse foreignkey modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

models.py:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = True)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete = models.RESTRICTED, null = True)
```

(One Member can be only part of one Team, but Team can have 0, one or any number of members)

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
```

Works as expected, but I want to make TeamForm:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name', ' member__team']
```

but it doesn't work (there's no member__team field)

I imagine form with multiplechoiceField - you can select from members which are connected with no team...

I made own forms.Form:

```
class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label = "Name", max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(), required = True)
    team_members = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Member.objects.filter(team__isnull=True).values_list('id','name'))
```

But has problem with updating:

views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
   team = Team.objects.create(name = form.cleaned_data['name'])
   #and now update all  members in form.cleaned_data['team_members'] with team= team
   # but how?
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd be best getting to grips with [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory)

There's a decent example project using these [here](https://github.com/studybuffalo/django-flexible-subscriptions/blob/master/subscriptions/views.py#L107)

Essentially you'd create something like this;

```py
class TeamForm(ModelForm):
    """Model Form for Team model."""
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name']


class MemberForm(ModelForm):
    """Form to use with inlineformset_factory and TeamForm."""
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ['name']


class TeamCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
    template_name = 'team_create.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overriding get method to handle inline formset."""
        # Setup the formset for Member
        MemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
            parent_model=Team,
            model=Member,
            form=MemberForm,
            can_delete=True,
            extra=1,
        )

        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
        member_forms = MemberFormSet()

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form,
                member_forms=member_forms,
            )
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overriding post method to handle inline formsets."""
        # Setup the formset for PlanCost
        MemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
            parent_model=Team,
            model=Member,
            form=MemberForm,
            can_delete=True,
            extra=1,
        )

        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
        member_forms = MemberFormSet(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and member_forms.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, member_forms)

        return self.form_invalid(form, member_forms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed class TeamForm multiplechoiceField into ModelMultipleChoiceField:

```
class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label = "Name", max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(), required = True)
    team_members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.filter(team__isnull=True))
```

and

```
 if form.is_valid():
      try:
          team = Team.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'])
          team_members = form.cleaned_data['team_members']
          for team_member in team_members:
              team_member.team = team
              team_member.save()
          form = NewPartyForm()
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
          pass
```

And works. Not sure if it is most django-style...